# How many different endings are there in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I recently hit a local game store and managed to secure one of a few copies of Fallout 4.

Now I've only started playing, and managed to progress through most of the main story (as I've heard there's plenty of side content, but I'd like to get the story over with), but I'm curious how many endings are there in the game?   I've heard that there are multiple endings from devstreams, but I'd like to know if there's only two endings (like white/black, good/bad), or are there endings like New Vegas' where siding with certain "factions" would change anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_endings), there are 4:

- Brotherhood Ending

> Supported by the rebuilt Liberty Prime, the Brotherhood assaults the Institute and blows up its reactor. For the player character's service, Elder Maxson promotes the Sole Survivor to the highest rank of Sentinel.

- Minutemen Ending

> The Institute is infiltrated and destroyed, sparing the Commonwealth of their oppression.

- Railroad Ending

> With the help of Deacon, Tinker Tom, and a stolen vertibird, the Sole Survivor infiltrate the Prydwen and destroy it from the inside, causing it to crash. Later, the Institute is infiltrated and destroyed. The two organizations most opposed to Synth freedom are eliminated and the Railroad can continue its work in relative peace.

- Institute Ending

> The Institute and the Sole Survivor attack and eliminate the Railroad. Later on, with the help of Institute synths, Liberty Prime is hacked and shoots the Prydwen out of the sky. After returning to the Institute, the Sole Survivor has a heart-to-heart with Father and assume his position after he dies.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ Try not to post spoiler comments responding to spoiler contents...

Answer (score 4):

You have 4 endings. Sadly, nothing you do aside from that will effect the end. It is not like New Vegas where you her to see the outcome of companions and side quests, it's actually rather bland.

Comment: I would sign under every word here.

Answer (score 2):

Actually guys, there are 5 endings. Brotherhood, Institute, Railroad and 2 Minute Men endings. The Minute Men ending has you destroy the Institute and Brotherhood but there is sort of a hidden ending where you kill off the Institute, but the other 3 factions can "live in peace" lmao.

The benefit of this outcome is you can get the side quests of the 3 surviving factions. Just don't talk to P.A.M. in the Railroad.

The only companion you lose doing this ending is X6-88 assuming you don't kill Danse. Speaking of which keep Danse away from the Brotherhood and the Railroad if you keep him alive. Trust me on this.

Comment: Also, you might want to put in spoiler tags on the spoiler parts.  Just in case someone doesn't want the specifics, but saying there are possibly 5 endings and which ones i think is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, you can check out the quest path these guys made: http://guides.gamepressure.com/fallout4/guide.asp?ID=32694

All of the quests are lisited here leading to a certain ending in the game. Hope this helps!

Comment: For future reference, you may want to take the content from the link and post it on SE directly to prevent link rot.